# How does one include data in crash dumps?

Tags: c++, c, crash-reports, crash-dumps, windows-error-reporting

I've started getting crash dumps from some alpha testers in a toy project of mine. At the moment, the app throws some C++ exception, which causes the app to crash. Watson comes along, and because I signed up for Windows Error Reporting, collects a crash dump and sends it to me. I would like to include information in this dump to help figure out what happened, such as the API call that was called to cause the error.

Is there some API or well-defined mechanism whereby I could note some things for the purpose of making dumps more useful just before or as part of throwing the potentially fatal exception?

Comment: Is your app .net or native?

Comment: Do you mean to say that you need to figure how to [analyze](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj933262.aspx) the crash dumps?  (The link is Windows 8 specific but the idea is the same on other variants of Windows.)

Comment: You may be able to add files using the `FilesToKeep` keyword in your manifest file.  I don't remember having much success with it but it has been a while since I tried.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219076%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Comment: @glag: Native, desktop.

Comment: @devnull: The relevant data is often on the heap -- it isn't getting collected as part of the normal crash dump process.

Comment: Are you looking to attach additional files?

Comment: @rrirower: No. I have a small amount of data which is on the heap, not the stack, so it isn't included in the dump. (e.g. the buffer backing a `std::string`)

Comment: From the [WER API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb513635(v=vs.85).aspx) functions...I haven't tried it, but, it looks like WerRegisterMemoryBlock may be of use.  However, I'd caution you on using those functions...WER tends to have a mind of it's own at times.

Comment: @rrirower: Given that right now I get nothing, it can't end up being too bad :)

Comment: You may try including heap information in the dump as http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181(v=vs.85).aspx ; though it is not clear whether WER will use that dump or a separate mini-dump in the report.

Comment: @glagolig: I don't want a full memory dump -- that can be huge. I just want to include the string buffer for the error message or similar that caused the failure.